# Go back to previews page angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in a project with Elixir/Phoenix and AngularJS. I have a button that should take the user to the previews page, but goBack() isn't working because I can get to the current page from two url

/games/list
/games/:id

goBack works perfectly when the previous page it's /games/list but it doesn't when it is /games/:id.

So how can I know the exact url from the previous page?

Comment: Can you provide some snippet showing the scopes this process takes place in?

Comment: This is a totally front end question. Removing the elixir and phoenix tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, $http,$timeout) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, toState, fromState,$timeout) {
    //toState your destination
    var des=toState;

    //fromState is your previous state



    var prevURL=fromState;
    });
    });
```